# Convert a datetime to date in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, date, conversion, convert

I have an issue converting a date/time to a string format date. Indeed, I would like to change the following date format : 'mardi 15 mars 2022 4:24 PM' to this format '15/03/2022' without the timedate. Do you know which function could I use to reach that ?

Thansk for your reply

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dateTimeFormatting.html

Comment: Hi @EazyE thanks for your reply. I would like to convert it from a SQL Query. I am not sure I can use an AMPSCRIPT to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the built-in [Format](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-date-functions/#format-with-dates) function that is perfect for your use case:

`Format(YourDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as StringifiedDate`.

Just remember that your destination data extension fields needs to be of the Text data type (the default length of 50 will be enough for this)

On a side note:
I recently had to do the same thing wanting to have my dates readable by Excel and wrote an [article about it](https://sfmc.quest/excelling-at-dates/) and the above solution is one of a few approaches that worked.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following SQL function (CONVERT):

```
SELECT CONVERT([data type], [value to convert], [style])
```

**The values inside the [] should be replaced with the values you would use:**

[data type] = This is the target data type to be converted. In your case, it would be datetime.

[value to convert] = the field in which you wish to convert to your desired date format.

[style] = the format in which you would like to convert to. In your case, this would be 3, but you can get a list of the options [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

Find out more about the CONVERT function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp).